# Is there any profiler tool for Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, profiling

VisualVM is an alternative for all of the Java apps ***to monitor performance***, in addition of this, jps and jmap may be helpful for profiling.

Spring has a web profiler for ***performance measurement, logs, events, queries etc***. Is there any free tools like this on web or desktop for Spring Framework?

[image: Spring Profiler Screenshot]

Comment: Off toic however SpringSource TC Server (drop in replacement for Tomcat) that has monitoring https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBqSh7nVNzc